# PHP too slow when sending emails through external SMTP server

Tags: php, performance, email, smtp

I have developed a PHP site to deliver a newsletter to subscribers through email using PHPMailer.

We had it hosted in a webhosting and it worked fine.
We moved to a new dedicated server and everything works faster, except the email sending.

Now it's unacceptably slow. It takes 5 seconds to send each email. (we have 200 subscribers right now, and growing)

I have traced the PHP code and I see the problem is the communication with the external SMTP Server (we use TurboSMTP). It takes 1 second each step in the communication (login, authentication, sending...)

I've use the curl_exec function to see the time to connect to some servers and I'm getting 1.2 seconds to TurboSMTP, and les than 0.1 seconds to Google, Gmail, and many other well known sites.

I verified that the Hosts file in Windows has this server correctly set.
I tried using the IP address instead the server name, and I get the same result.
A "ping" to the TurboSMTP server (pro.turbo-smtp.com) is fast, as fast a to the IP 199.187.175.15

My server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS.

I've compared the configuration of the PHP ini in my new server with the old one, and I don't see substantial differences...  (I don't have the ini file of the old server, but i can see the configuration of the PHP)

Any idea? I've been wasting time for two weeks with this and my users are loosing their patience...  :(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are sending an email upon submission of a form then your users are at the mercy of the slowest link in your chain of events; TurboSMTP in your situation. The proper way to do this would be to create an email queue and run a scheduled task which sends the emails on it's own time. This will help you create a separation of concerns and tweak the email stuff on an as needed basis.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But I still have the time of sending the emails, which is a big concern. 200 emails, at 5 seconds each, equals 16 minutes... more than one hour if we have 1000 subscribers... the delivery time of the newsletter is critical. We deliver a news report that must be in our subscriber's inboxes before 08:00 am.... also the users have to tell the systema when the newsletter is ready to be sent... That's why we use a form... Also...I don't think the problem is TurboSMTP. It used to work fine when I have the system in other web server... (Thanks for your answer)

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your entire process. Is it feasible to simply BCC every recipient into one email and only suffer a single 5-second email?

Comment: Mmm... no. Each email is personalized. The subscriber can choose which sections receive (the newsletter has many sections), and we add tracking code in each email. We have an interface to upload to our server news, images, comments, etc. When the "edition" of the newsletter is closed, then it is sent to the subscribers.

Comment: Would you be able to find out how far physically your new dedicated server is from the TurboSMTP server? Geographical distance between servers does make a difference.

Comment: Its quite far... yes... My server is in Buenos Aires, Argentina. TurboSMTP, I think, is in USA. But I don't think this is a problem. My previous hosting was in Argentina too, and it used to work fine when sending emails...   (I mean 30 or 50 times faster.)

Comment: Mmm... I just figured out that my previous web server is not in Argentina, but in USA (Texas), and TurboSMTP is in New York... Perhaps you are right... But the Google ip is located in California, and my server can communicate well and fast with that server... Mmmmm.....

Comment: Since moving to your new server has caused many unknown changes in configuration I would recommend using [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to properly debug this issue. You should monitor your server's network traffic and identify how long the TCP/IP transmission actually takes. This will let you know whether it is an issue in your application (website) or the network. You should also follow up with your hosting provider and eventually TurboSMTP and see if they know of a resolution.

Comment: If your new server is in Buenos Aires then it makes perfect sense that the SMTP communication has increased significantly. You might want to find an SMTP service closer to home or switch to a U.S. based dedicated server.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently MonkeyZeus was right.
I used Wireshark to snif the net and see what was taking so long... And I found there is nothing especifically slow...

It's just taking that time the handshaking and the communication itself.

The problem is that I migrated the server from one hosting in California, to a dedicated server in Buenos Aires, and the SMTP server is in NewYork.

Believe it or not, the distance does matter.

Every communication with the server means 10.000 km to go, and another 10.000 km back (Assuming we have an optical fiber that goes stright from Buenos Aires to NewYork) even at light speed, this 20.000 km round trip mean almost 70 miliseconds... And if we do the math... it takes seconds to send an email.
HTH

Comment: There are lots of things you could be doing to address the latency problem. Even without running your own MTA you could batch up in correspondents in the envelope bcc, and/or process the sending in concurrent threads. And even at a 70ms RTT that's really slow to send an email (should be around 5 rtts + bandwidth cost, 8 rtts if you are using TLS)